# How to auto add image caption from image alt?

Tags: images, captions

How to automatically copy image alt to caption/description in WordPress?

Comment: What have you tried? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/344516/edit) to add any relevant code.

Comment: When are you trying to do this?  when an image is uploaded ?  Or go through all the images on your site?  We need a bit more details.

Comment: If possible go through all the images on my site.

Comment: Existing images is going to be very difficult, because you need to parse the HTML of your post/page content, extract the alt text, and then replace the HTML of the image with the HTML required for captions.

Comment: I can't believe how hard this simple need is. Four years and no answer?